# How to display Customised error message on website if its Database goes down

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, iis-7

I have a `ASP.NET` website with `SQL SERVER` Database. Each time database goes down it shows a .NET error message. Is there any way to display a customised message. For eg: "Sorry, website is currently unavailable."

Comment: Look at `<customErrors>` section

Comment: You can also add `try catch` block for `SqlException` and redirect in case of latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use try catch and handle SQL Exception and in the catch block add the customised message to your label.

Answer (score 1):

Get the exception in the Global.asax and redirect them, see [this](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/961301/Global-Exception-Handling-with-ASPNET.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Create and set errorpage for your website
Check [Web Application Error Hanling](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_debugging/article.php/c19411/Web-Application-Error-Handling-in-ASPNET.htm)